# Vanilla JS App - Function to generate error message malfunctioning

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a simple app to convert Fahrenheit, Celsius, and Kelvin into one another.  The app is written in HTML and Vanilla JS.  Here's the code:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('temperatureForm').addEventListener('submit', calculate)
const degreesToBeConverted = document.getElementById('degreesToBeConverted');

const fahrenheitToCelsiusRadioButton = document.getElementById('fahrenheitToCelsiusRadioButton')
const fahrenheitToKelvinRadioButton = document.getElementById('fahrenheitToKelvinRadioButton')

const celsiusToFahrenheitRadioButton = document.getElementById('celsiusToFahrenheitRadioButton')
const celsiusToKelvinRadioButton = document.getElementById('celsiusToKelvinRadioButton')

const kelvinToCelsiusRadioButton = document.getElementById('kelvinToCelsiusRadioButton')
const kelvinToFahrenheitRadioButton = document.getElementById('kelvinToFahrenheitRadioButton')

const resetButton = document.getElementById('resetButton');




function calculate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let resultField = document.getElementById('resultField');
  let valueOfDegreesToBeConvertedField = degreesToBeConverted.value.length

  if (fahrenheitToCelsiusRadioButton.checked == true) {
    let x = (degreesToBeConverted.value - 32) * .5556;
    resultField.value = x.toFixed(1);

  } else if (fahrenheitToKelvinRadioButton.checked == true) {
    let x = (degreesToBeConverted.value - 32) * .5556 + 273.15;
    resultField.value = x.toFixed(1);
  } else if (celsiusToFahrenheitRadioButton.checked == true) {
    let x = (degreesToBeConverted.value * 1.8) + 32;
    resultField.value = x.toFixed(1);
  } else if (celsiusToKelvinRadioButton.checked == true) { // Uncaught TypeError: x.toFixed is not a function at HTMLFormElement.calculate
    let x = parseFloat(degreesToBeConverted.value) + 273.15;
    console.log(typeof x);
    resultField.value = x.toFixed(1);
  } else if (kelvinToCelsiusRadioButton.checked == true) { // Uncaught TypeError: x.toFixed is not a function at HTMLFormElement.calculate
    let x = parseFloat(degreesToBeConverted.value) - 273.15;
    resultField.value = x.toFixed(1);
  } else if (kelvinToFahrenheitRadioButton.checked == true) {
    let x = ((degreesToBeConverted.value - 273.15) * 9 / 5) + 32;
    resultField.value = x.toFixed(1);
  } else if (fahrenheitToCelsiusRadioButton.checked == false && celsiusToFahrenheitRadioButton.checked == false) {
    showError('Please tick a button')
  }

  if (valueOfDegreesToBeConvertedField === 0) {
    resultField.value = '';
    showError('Please type a number in the box')
  }
}

function showError(error) {
  // Create a Div

  const errorDiv = document.createElement('div');

  // Get Elements

  const card = document.querySelector('.card');
  const heading = document.querySelector('.heading');

  // Add class

  errorDiv.className = 'alert alert-danger';

  // Create Text Node & Append to Div

  errorDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(error));

  // Insert error above heading

  card.insertBefore(errorDiv, heading); // This means 'insert errorDiv before heading'

  // Clear error after 3 seconds

  setTimeout(clearError, 3000);
}

// Clear error

function clearError() {
  document.querySelector('.alert').remove();
}


function reloadPage() {
  location.reload();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-primary">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card-body text-center mt-5">
          <h1 class="heading display-5 pb-3">Temperature Converter</h1>

          <form id="temperatureForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="fahrenheitToCelsiusRadioButton">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">Fahrenheit to Celsius?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="fahrenheitToKelvinRadioButton">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">Fahrenheit to Kelvin? &nbsp;</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="celsiusToFahrenheitRadioButton">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">Celsius to Fahrenheit?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="celsiusToKelvinRadioButton">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">Celsius to Kelvin? &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="kelvinToCelsiusRadioButton">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">Kelvin to Celsius? &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="kelvinToFahrenheitRadioButton">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">Kelvin to Fahrenheit? &nbsp;</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group mb-3 mt-3">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Enter figure</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="degreesToBeConverted" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-success col-6 mt-3">
            </div>
          </form>



          <div id="results">
            <h5 class="pt-4">Results</h5>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group mb-3 mt-3">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="nothingImportant">Result</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="resultField" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Reset" id="resetButton" onclick="reloadPage()" class="btn btn-warning col-3 mt-3">
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The app requires users to do three things:

(a) Input a figure into a field called 'Enter Figure'.
(b) Click one of several radio buttons in order to choose which units to convert that figure from and to.
(c) Press a 'Calculate' button to perform the conversion.

For example, if you entered 50 and chose 'Celsius to Fahrenheit' the program would convert 50 Celsius into Fahrenheit and return 122.

The calculation aspect all works fine.  The issue I'm having concerns custom error messages that I've built into the program.

If a user presses the 'Calculate' button without inputting a figure, the program inserts an error message reading **"Please type a number in the box"**.  If a user *has* typed a figure in the box but *hasn't* selected which units to convert that figure from and to, the program inserts *another* error message which says **"Please select a button"**.  If a user hasn't selected a button *or* typed a figure in the box, both error messages will show up.  Each error message is programmed to disappear after three seconds

Here's the problem.  If a user hasn't filled everything in correctly and then presses the 'Calculate' button over and over again very quickly, the error messages will just keep piling up.  What I mean is, if a user hasn't filled in the 'Enter Figure' field and then presses 'Calculate' ten times very quickly, the program will generate ten separate error messages, one on top of the other, each reading **"Please type a number in the box"**.

I think this looks very unprofessional and I've spent the morning trying various methods to get rid of it but nothing has worked.  If anyone knows of a way to fix this problem I'd very much appreciate it.

Here's a codepen with the HTML and JS code:

https://codepen.io/Nellington/pen/eYWveyw

Comment: Each time you insert a new error message, you can check & remove all the error messages with this class before inserting the new one

Comment: Another way to handle it, will be to have a error element directly in your html code & just replace all the content each time with `textContent`

Answer (score 0):

Based on 2nd Wax comment :

```
var timeoutHandler = null;

function showError(error) {
    let errorDiv = document.getElementById('errorDiv');

    if (!errorDiv) {
        // Creates the error div
        errorDiv = document.createElement('div');
        error.id = "errorDiv";

        // Get Elements
        const card = document.querySelector('.card');
        const heading = document.querySelector('.heading');

        // Add class
        errorDiv.className = 'alert alert-danger';

        // Insert error above heading
        card.insertBefore(errorDiv, heading); // This means 'insert errorDiv before heading'
    }

    // Remove current error message
    errorDiv.innerHTML = '';

    // Create Text Node & Append to Div
    errorDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(error));

    // Clear error after 3 seconds
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandler)
    timeoutHandler = setTimeout(clearError, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post.  Unfortunately, your solution doesn't solve the problem.  The error messages still pile up, but now they don't go away after three seconds like they used to.